# Angular Console: Can't create library

Tags: nrwl, nrwl-nx, angular-cli-v8, angular-console

I'm trying to create a new library using v 8.1.0 of the Angular Console on Windows.  The error I get is **"ENOENT: no such file or directory, mkdir "c:\path\to\my\workspace\libs\new_library_name"**

**"c:\path\to\my\workspace\libs"** exists already

**new_library_name** folder should be created by Angular Console

The command run by the console is `ng generate @nrwl/angular:library new_library_name`.

I've tried different names/paths, running as administrator, running inside VSCode and in the standalone console.  No luck with anything.  This used to work.

Also, if I create the folder **c:\path\to\my\workspace\libs\new_library_name** and then run the console again, I get an error **ENOENT: no such file or directory c:\path\to\my\workspace\libs\new_library_name\ReadMe.md**.  Of course the ReadMe doesn't exist - it needs to be created by the console.

What am I doing wrong or where to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had turned on Controlled Folder Access in Windows 10 and mistakenly included my project folder as a controlled folder, which prevented applications (Angular Console, Yarn, etc) from writing to the folder.  Removed it from Controlled Access and all is working again.